# How to properly run a docker container on an interval?

Tags: docker, cron, containers

I currently run a service that spins virtualized testbeds in Openstack that have a set expiration time. This service currently runs in a docker container. However, to decouple the cleanup (expiration time handling) I have a separate script that acts as an independent client and issues delete requests to the service. They currently live in the same container.

The docker entry point looks something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Used by Docker in order to run both the server and the
# cleaner process at the same time.  When server dies
# or is killed, cleaner is killed as well to ensure that
# the container exits.
#

# turn on bash's job control
set -m

# Start the primary process and put it in the background
poetry run waitress-serve --port=5000 --threads=8 --call "server:app.create_app" &

# Write cleaner.cfg file
cat << EOF > /etc/cleaner.ini
[conf]
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 5000
EOF

# Start the helper process
poetry run cleaner -c /etc/cleaner.ini &

# now we bring the primary process back into the foreground
# and leave it there
fg %1

# Once the primary process dies, lets kill the helper
# script
kill %2
```

This has been working ok... but it has become and issue in that if the cleaner hangs or dies due to a bug I introduced or something else, I need to manually re-enter the container and restart the cleaner in the background. The other issue is the logs get lost in the server logs and it is hard to see when an issue occurs. The cleaner only ever runs every 15 minutes.

I would like to break it out into it's own container. I would like to remove the sleep from the python cleaner script and have the script be called on an interval. I understand that Cron does not perform well in the docker context:

1. Cron Daemon would be separate process
2. How to handle stdout to support `docker  logs ...`?
3. How does cron handle hung processes?

Taking that into consideration. I would really like to have the "Cron" aspect be from outside the docker container. Just `docker run` every 15 minutes. Has anyone done something like this? Is there any native support? And most importantly is there a way to preserve/attach logs between runs so logs are not lost on each spin? Google didn't point me to any resources that were helpful. Thank you.